# Daily logrotate doesn't keep the old logs

Tags: centos6, logrotate

On a CentOS 6.x I created a simple service called `logtraffic` which, when started, appends the output of a `tcpdump` command to a log file at `/var/log/logtraffic/logtraffic.log`.

I want to achieve the following regarding that log:

- have that log rotated daily at midnight
- keep the latest 7 logs and delete the older ones

For this, I've done the following:

- commented the following line from /etc/anacrontab

`1      5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily`

- added the following cron job:
  `@midnight /etc/cron.daily/logrotate`
- created the file `/etc/logrotate.d/logtraffic` with the content:

```
/var/log/logtraffic/*log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    create
    dateext
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /sbin/service logtraffic restart > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Looks like the log is properly truncated at midnight as the timestamps displayed in logtraffic.log prove that.

The problem is that no other older log file is present in that folder. I was expecting to have older logs with a suffix like YYYYMMDD but there are none.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does a manual run of logrotate tell you?

Comment: I ran: 'logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf' and it gave me the following:
'rotating pattern: /var/log/logtraffic/*log  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/logtraffic/logtraffic.log
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated'

Comment: By the way, I see that I got -3 (so far) for my question. I always try to improve the quality of both my answers and my questions on the Stack Exchange sites.
Therefore, I would appreciate a short explanation beside a -1. I'm not upset or anything like this. I just want to learn. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the issue. I changed the content of `/etc/logrotate.d/logtraffic` with the following code:

```
/var/log/logtraffic/*log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    create
    dateext
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        /sbin/service logtraffic stop > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
    postrotate
        /sbin/service logtraffic start > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

I still don't understand why it didn't work with my previous settings, but at least it is fixed now.